# What is the right pattern to close an OdbcConnection in an asp.net-mvc web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc, data-access-layer, dispose

I have a website and I have a data access class that has an OdbcConnection.  In the constructor I have this code:

```
    public MySybaseProvider()
    {
        _conn = GetConn();        
    }

    public OdbcConnection GetConn()
    {
        string connString = "DSN=SybaseIQ;Eng=SYSERVER;Links=tcpip(Host=" + _connectionInfo.Host + ";Port=" + _connectionInfo.Port + ");UID=" + _connectionInfo.User + ";PWD=" + _connectionInfo.Pwd + ";";

        return new OdbcConnection(connString);
    }
```

and through out the class i have the following code:

```
    private OdbcQuery GetQuery(string sql)
    {
        return new OdbcQuery(_conn, sql);
    }
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to make sure I close the connection properly.  Should I implement IDisposable?  should i open and close the connection on each query?  Are there any other best practices here.

### EDIT:

To clarify, my use case is that i am loading a single web page but it takes about 10 queries to get all of the data needed for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [ODBC connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx) is enabled, and create and open a connection object with the `using` statement for each of your accesses to the database:

```
using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(_connString)) {
  conn.Open();

  // do a database command ...
}
```

(Note that I changed the design to store your `_connString` in a field)

This is the most *idiomatic* way to do this, and you don't need to worry about creating your connection in the constructor, storing it in a field, or even implementing `IDisposable`.

Comment: are you saying i should do this? :         private OdbcQuery GetQuery(string sql)
        {
            using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(GetConnString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var odbc = new OdbcQuery(conn, sql);
                conn.Close();
                return odbc;
            }
        }

Comment: or do I not need to have a conn.Close because of the using statement ?

Comment: To clarify, my use case is that i am loading a single web page but it takes about 10 queries to get all of the data needed for the page. I am trying to figure out if i should open the connection once or for each queryand then close conn

Comment: No, I'm just saying that you should use that pattern in each method that accesses the DB, apparently _inside_ that `OdbcQuery` class. And you don't need to call `Close`.

Answer (score 1):

So I have submitted another Answer Because I realised that I usually use Enterprise Library for my Data Access and not pure .net which changes things a bit. For one the DataAccessApplicationBlock (DAAB) takes care of opening and closing the Connection(s) to the Database so I don't have too, therefore I use it like below. Also in this case a easier and more effiecint way to do what is described is to execute all the SELECT Statements in 1 Stored Proc and Then Read through and Parse each result set one at a time.

Example:

Stored Proc

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserByEmail]
    @UserID int,
    @AccountID int,
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID and AccountID = @AccountID

    SELECT * FROM UserAddresses WHERE UserID = @UserID
END
```

C# Code:

```
public class DataAccessLayer
{
    private static DataAccessLayer me = new DataAccessLayer();

    private DataAccessLayer() { }

    public static DataAccessLayer GetInstance()
    {
        return me;
    }

    public Database GetDatabase(string connectionString, string provider)
    {
       DbProviderFactory providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);

        return new GenericDatabase(connectionString,
                                   providerFactory);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    protected Database curDatabase;

    public Repository()
    {
        curDatabase = DataAccessLayer.GetInstance().GetDatabase("ConnectionString", "System.Data.Odbc");
    }

    public Database CurrentDatabase
    {
        get { return curDatabase; }
    }
}

public class UserRepository : Repository
{
    public User GetUser(int urserID, int accountID)
    {
        using (IDataReader dataReader = CurrentDatabase.ExecuteReader("StroedProcName", urserID, accountID))
        {
            //User Details
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                //Parse Data
            }

            dataReader.NextResult();

            //User Address(es)
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                //Parse Data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue you definitely should implement `IDisposable` and follow the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Keep in mind the garbage collector knows nothing about `IDisposable`. You should as a last resort have a finalizer that will kill the DB connection if need be, but suppress the finalizer whenever possible (see the link I added for all the gory details).

As to whether you want to create a new connection per command or keep one around for the life of the object, that's much more subjective and depends on your scenario, environment, and many other things. I recommend exploring both and see what you think. If this is a "real" DB, perhaps talk to the DBA and see what they think.

Either way, implementing `IDisposable` is your friend, as you can have nice, clean, well defined disposing code in a pattern that all .NET developers are familiar with.

Comment: so are you saying that when my object goes out of scope it will automatically call the dispose method?  I don't understand what you mean by "finalizer" because i am initiating the connection in the class constructor

Comment: To clarify, my use case is that i am loading a single web page but it takes about 10 queries to get all of the data needed for the page. I am trying to figure out if i should open the connection once or for each query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern to ensure the connection is disposed.  Even if an error occurs it will be disposed of.  For safer coding you should use a connection string builder to build the connection.  You should only create / use the connection when you are planning to perform an operation.  It should NOT hang around for the life of your application.  You can use the connection string / properties for that instead.

```
    public OdbcConnection GetConn()
    {
        OdbcConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.Driver = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";
        sb.Add("Dbq", "C:\\info.mdb");
        sb.Add("Uid", "Admin");
        sb.Add("Pwd", "pass!word1");
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(sb.ConnectionString);
        return con;
    }


    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        using(OdbcConnection connection = GetConn())
        {
            // Do stuff with your connection here


        }
    }
```

Comment: but them i am creating a connection for every query i run

Comment: A down vote for what?  These are database best practices to be used on production systems.  You should only hold the connection for as long as you are going to use it without any major processing or user interaction.

Comment: You NEVER hold onto connections in an application.  You release them as soon as you don't need them anymore.  If you have multiple queries to run at the same time - you can use the same connection for it - but don't keep it open for situations like waiting on user input, long running operations (processing), etc.

Comment: The use case i have is to run about 10 queries for the page to load

Comment: To clarify, my use case is that i am loading a single web page but it takes about 10 queries to get all of the data needed for the page. I am trying to figure out if i should open the connection once or for each query

Comment: It really depends on how you are doing this though - are you building everything up in a class, are you reaching across multiple classes, etc.  Your architecture should be designed as such to limit the time connections are open.  Also are you using transactions?

Comment: these are all read queries so no transactions.  I am simple creating a class, running 10 queries and stories the results in a viewModel and them returning a view